# Using Sikuli to take automated screenshots of a window?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sikuli

Simple question here: I'd like to use Sikuli to take a screenshot of a window on a mac, which would be done by hitting CMD+SHIFT+4 then hitting Space, then clicking a window.

For the CMD+SHIFT+4 I'm having trouble. This doesn't work:

```
keyDown(KEY_META)
keyDown(Key.SHIFT)
wait(1)
type("4")
wait(1)
keyUp(Key.SHIFT)
keyUp(KEY_META)
```

Anyone have any ideas? I'm open to other routes of hitting the key combo, for instance, I know to copy this works well:

```
type("c",KEY_META)
```

But, it doesn't accept three arguments.

Comment: Are there any other known outputs of command-shift-4 inside a separate window/application?

Comment: No, it's a system reserved keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
type("4", KeyModifier.CMD+KeyModifier.SHIFT)
```

Or, even better:

```
import shutil
import os
screenshotsDir = "absolute-path-to-a-folder"
img = capture(some_region)
shutil.move(img, os.path.join(screenshotsDir, "some-name.png"))
```

where some_region is:

```
some_region = SCREEN # for whole screen
```

or

```
someRegion = App.focusedWindow() # for the frontmost window
```

This has the advantage, that you can control the file name of the shot.

Answer (score 1):

Have found a better solution, which actually works:

```
screen = Screen()
scr_img = screen.capture(screen.getBounds())
scr_img.save("C:\Screenshots", "screenshot")
```

Screen.capture() returns an instance of ScreenImage class with methods:'save', 'saveInBundle', 'getFile', 'getFilename'. The method save() adds an unique number to a supplied prefix parameter.

Comment: This will capture the whole screen **not**, _as asked_, just a specific window.